# How to configure Drupal email functionality on GoDaddy server

Tags: email, server, godaddy, drupal

I have Drupal 6 installed on a GoDaddy server. The email functionality used to work fine, but about a month ago they moved my site to their newer generation of server, and I discovered today after setting up some triggers that Drupal is no longer sending emails, including contact form emails.

Can anyone direct me to a concise guide to configuring Drupal email functionality in general, or specifically for GoDaddy? I tried looking on GoDaddy's support site but couldn't find anything useful (big surprise there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Drupal's SMTP module with GoDaddy's outgoing mailserver. This forces Drupal to send email using GoDaddy's mailserver instead of PHP's `mail()` function, which is probably disabled on the new GoDaddy server, as is common with shared hosting packages.

1. Download the [SMTP module](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) for Drupal 6.
2. Copy the files included in the download into a directory named "smtp" in
   your Drupal sites/all/modules/ directory.
3. Download the [PHPMailer package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/) and place it in a directory named "phpmailer" in your /sites/all/modules/smtp directory.
4. Login as site administrator.
5. Enable the SMTP Authentication Support module under Administer -> Site
   building -> Modules.
6. Fill in settings for your SMTP (outgoing mail) server on the Administer -> Site configuration -> SMTP
   Authentication Support page. To send mail through GoDaddy's server, use 'smtpout.secureserver.net' for the address, turn encryption (SSL) off, authentication on, set the port to 80, and use your GoDaddy account email address and password (the same ones you use to log in to their [webmail service](https://login.secureserver.net/index.php)).

Comment: That worked SO WELL. It appears to have done exactly what I wanted. At first I thought it wasn't working, but then I realized I was using my go-daddy provided email address, which I check with gmail, as the recipient, so the fact that Gmail only checks that address for me periodically was introducing an extra delay. Any thoughts on how to have my godaddy email address (e.g. me@myself.com) be the recipient without a delay like this? Thanks.

Comment: If you currently have Gmail set up to check your GoDaddy email account for new mail periodically using Gmail's Mail Fetcher service, I recommend turning that off and simply forwarding all email addressed to you@yourdomain.com to you@gmail.com. You can then set up a ['send mail as' address](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=22370) in Gmail to send email from that account too if you haven't already. Forwarding mail instead of having Gmail fetch it negates any delay caused by the fetch interval.

Comment: That's what I wanted to do, but from what I can see, mail forwarding is a service Godaddy charges for. I don't see anywhere in their webmail interface to set this up; if I go to filters, the only actions allowed are to move messages to another folder. What I've done instead is to just have Drupal itself send emails to my Gmail directly. Then if I want I can reply from my gmail or my own domain using 'send mail' as you suggested.

Comment: Hai.. I am getting the same problem.  For me email is going for all other email addresses but its not going for my @site.com address it is hosted in godaddy.  Actually I have not pointed my DNS to the site yet I am testing it by my local DNS.  I am not sure the email not received my admin is because of the DNS pointing.. Please help..

Comment: @DilipRajkumar This sounds like a DNS problem to me. You may wish to [start a new question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and explain your problem in more detail. It's not entirely clear from your comment what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I have this question already in Stack overflow http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28706/smtp-authentication-in-drupal please let me know if you need more information..Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't installed the SMTP module, get it [here](https://drupal.org/project/smtp).

Then under *Configuration->System->SMTP Authentication Support*:

Set the value of field SMTP server to: **relay-hosting**.secureserver.net

Set the SMTP Port to: 25

Don't use any encrypted protocol. Also leave the fields "username" and "password" empty.